# Python Subprocess nbtstat "cannot find the file"

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having difficulty getting an nbtstat command to run in python. Whenever I run the following code, I get the error "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

```
print(subprocess.check_output(["nbtstat","-A",ipaddress]))
```

I've also tried

```
print(subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Windows\\System32\\nbtstat.exe","-A",ipaddress]))
```

and

```
print(subprocess.check_output("nbtstat -A "+ipaddress))
```

and none of these versions worked.

Is there something I'm missing from the command to get it to run properly?

---

On Windows running python 2.7.11 (cannot update)

Comment: Can you run `nbtstat` from the same `Command Prompt` you're running your Python from? What do you get if you try to run it indirectly through another shell (i.e. `subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "/c", "nbtstat"])`)?

Comment: @abarnert - on 64-bit Windows `%WINDIR%\system32` actually contains 64-bit binaries (or 32-bit binaries if there is no 64-bit version of a specific one)

Comment: @zwer Yeah, I remembered that after I wrote it… but meanwhile, while searching, I discovered that `nbtstat` actually _is_ 32-bit-only, at least in the last version I could find documented, and Wikipedia agrees, so… I was just going to come back and delete my comment.

Comment: @zwer - Yes. Typing it into the command prompt works just fine.

Comment: @zwer - I tested using cmd instead and I get the same error.

Comment: @zwer - I looked up stuff about nbtstat and discovered that it is 64-bit only and I was trying to run it from a 32-bit script. I posted my foll answer to this question for archival purposes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @abarnert - I don't know what you posted, but it looks like it was related to the answer I eventually found. So thank you as well!

Comment: Out of curiosity (great answer!) -- when you said "typing it into the command prompt works fine" -- were you just typing in `nbtstat`, or were you typing in `c:\Windows\system32\nbtstat.exe`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Both. They both worked fine. The problem was the script being 32-bit trying to open a 64-bit executable. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I saw the answer (hence the compliment); it's just... surprising... that `cmd.exe` would implicitly redirect an explicit request to run the 32-bit `system32` copy over to `sysnative`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Yeah, I dunno, man. It certainly feels like the Windows native applications play by their own strange rules, both cmd.exe and Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the command as a path to the executable and trade \System32 for \sysnative .

This command works as desired:

```
print(subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\nbtstat.exe","-A",ipaddress]))
```

---

[This page describes the sysnative folder,](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) but I will give a short (and VERY oversimplified) explanation here:

System32 and Sysnative are actually the same folder just accessed through different names, but if the program using the folder is 32-bit, then the name you use to access this folder changes what options are available in the folder. If the 32-bit program uses the System32 path, then only 32-bit options are available, and all 64-bit programs are hidden. If it instead uses the Sysnative path, then the 64-bit options become available.

As it turns out, nbtstat.exe is actually a 64 bit program, and so when a 32-bit script or other program tries to open it through the System32 folder, it returns an error saying that the program doesn't exist. And since the default path to look for commands is System32, if you don't specify a path, then it will also say the program doesn't exist.

Because of this, in order for a 32-bit program to use a 64-bit command executable, you must explicitly specify the path of the execuatable, and it must be specified through the Sysnative path instead of the System32 path.